# Deploying Java Application on a server

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I created a server application for my program that manages accounts, which involves saving data, and constantly recieving connections. How would I go about putting that on a server? Would I use Tomcat? And if so, how?

Comment: u mean to say remote server..?

Comment: Yeah, remotely hosting by another company.

Comment: use tomcat only no issues, and u have to install tomcat in your remote server and jdk thats it . Your application can be hosted.

Comment: yeah you can use tomcat

Answer (score 0):

1. Pack your application into WAR archive
2. Copy your WAR into "tomcat directory"/webapps
3. Run Tomcat

Comment: Does this work for programs that are not console applications? Like, are there any particular things I need to do beforehand?

Comment: The application should be web application. So, you should use HTTP to communicate with it.